# Failing to find views when using slugs and class based views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, slug

One of my Django apps, "Pages", has many different classes in the models.py. Each of them have a slug attribute/field of their own. I'm able to load the URL for the first   - "company" (first class) but for some reason can't load the other URLs.

I have tried importing the views separately and creating urls paths for each view. When doing this, only the last URLs (third one) would load.

**models.py**

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.industry
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.industry)

            super(Industry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('industry_detail', args=[(self.slug)])

class Subindustry(models.Model):
    subindustry = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    industry = models.ForeignKey(
        Industry,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ParentIndustry',
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subindustry
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.subindustry)

            super(Subindustry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('subindustry_detail', args=[(self.slug)])



class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True, default=(str(id)))
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)

            super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('company_detail', args=[(self.slug)])
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

# Create your views here.
from .models import Company, Industry, Subindustry

class CompanyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company_detail.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'

class IndustryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Industry
    slug_field = 'slug'
    template_name = 'industry_detail.html'


class SubindustryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Subindustry
    slug_field = 'slug'
    template_name = 'subindustry_detail.html'
```

**urls.py (Pages app)**

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import CompanyDetailView, IndustryDetailView, SubindustryDetailView

urlpatterns = [
     path('<slug:slug>/', CompanyDetailView.as_view(), name='company_detail'),
     path('<slug:slug>/', IndustryDetailView.as_view(), name='industry_detail'),
     path('<slug:slug>/', SubindustryDetailView.as_view(), name='subindustry_detail'),
]
```

**urls.py (Project level)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path(r'aoa/', include('qa.urls')),
    path('business/', include('pages.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
]
```

Expected: Seeing the page when entering right url. E.g. if i try loading http://127.0.0.1:8000/business/construction/ it will load (this is an Industry value for example). Currently only company values load, e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/business/macrodepot/ Please note that I do have the HTMLs templates for each class and I am able to see them if I only have one of them in the views.py file.

Actual: The below 404 is received when i enter the url for an industry or subindustry. It's as if is looking for the slug only in the companydetailview.

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/business/construction/
Raised by:  pages.views.CompanyDetailView
No company found matching the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because django evaluates the urls in the order they are placed in urlpatterns. It receives a request to businesses/construction and calls CompanyDetailView which returns a 404. You need to have a different url pattern for each model:

```
    urlpatterns = [
     path('company/<slug:slug>/', CompanyDetailView.as_view(), name='company_detail'),
     path('industry/<slug:slug>/', IndustryDetailView.as_view(), name='industry_detail'),
     path('subindustry/<slug:slug>/', SubindustryDetailView.as_view(), name='subindustry_detail'),
]
```